# QTP or selenium or something else?

Tags: selenium, vbscript, automation, qtp, sahi

I have so far been a partly QA Automation/partly Web developer person, mostly been working on **QTP / VBScript** for Automation.
Soon I will be moving on to a new project as Automation Architect. 
While I have the overall approach and idea for Automation Framework, that I want to develop, ready in my mind, I need some help on deciding the Automation tool. I would love to use QTP as I would be able to use  the full library for low level functions as is from my current project. 
 
However one thing where I feel restrained with QTP is **‘cross browser’** support, I feel only IE can be targeted best with QTP, Firefox/Chrome support is still bit limited. Also, QTP doesn’t allow to test on multiple browser windows at a time. (I maybe wrong here, the latest QTP version maybe supporting this, and if so, I will appreciate if you can share  your experience)
  Our target apps would mostly be Web Application and target Web platforms would be IE/Chrome/Firefox/Safari/Opera. 
So I am also thinking to give **Selenium** or **Sahi**  a try. 
Being a Web developer, I can say I am good at JavaScript, so adapting to Selenium should not be a big shift for me. 
 
 
However before I go ahead with getting my hands dirty with Selenium, I want to hear the thoughts from the expert community here.  
What do you feel, how good has been yours ‘cross browser’ automation experience with Selenium /Sahi, or your grievances w.r.to Selenium.
  Also how much Selenium would be helpful to when it comes to something like the flexibility we get from QTP in terms of opening the door for Automation Developers to VBscripting world – we can extend the scripts using lot of supporting VBScripts , system level scripting, or networking related scripting or IE settings programming , runtime DLL registrations or other  batch files, database linking (ADODB), using 3rd party APIs / Web APIs etc, XML programming, using .net libraries etc.

thanks in advance, much appreciate sharing your valuable experience.

Comment: You should gave a read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

This is an ongoing debate. However, I, from my experience, would say SELENIUM. There are of course some advantages of using QTP. However, with the ongoing technology in development world selenium is much better tool. Having the capability of implementing the OOP and taking it's advantage is a big factor here where qtp easily fails. Thinking abount angulars, other ajax technology where selenium is improving day by day and qtp is not. And, think about working in agile team side by side with developers who are building your app with java/c#. You can pretty much share there knowledge and techniques to equally support your project where using qtp your project set up will be whole lot different. And, at any case if you need help from google selenium wins without any doubt.